# SSH remote login from wan fail but logging in from lan works

Tags: linux, ssh

I use certificate authentication to login to my home computer from my laptop. Everything works fine on the lan.

When i try to connect from outside my home network(using my mobile as ap) it fails.

I use ddns and it resolves to my public ip. I have port forwared from port 5556 to port 22 to the computer used as SSH server. I also tried to port forward from port 22 to 22.

I connect using this command:

```
ssh -v -XC -p 5556 [my ddns hostname]
```

output is:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [my ddns hostname] [my pub ip address] port 5556
debug1: connect to address [my pub ip address] port 5556: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host [my ddns hostname] port 5556: Connection timed out
```

line 19 in my config file is

```
Host *
```

What could be my problem? I do not get it, it works on my lan just fine:S

---

### My sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22

# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

AllowUsers *@*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the absence of reply from the server, it looks like there is a firewall preventing access to that port, most probably set by your ISP. (Assuming your mobile connection is reliable)

Check in the logs of the SSH server whether it receives connections requests.

You can also run the `nmap` command against your ddns hostname to seen which ports are open.

Comment: Tried oprt 80, does not work either:S this port schould not be blocked by any isp or router in between right? (also changed the port forwarding 80->22)

Comment: I also have a webservice that I successfully can visit. It is on port 5356

Comment: Some ISPs have a policy to block nearly all incoming ports for residential users, leading them to pay for a professional service to be able to host a webserver, etc.

Comment: Did you try the nmap command?

Comment: ill perform nmap scan now to see whats up. Just a little afraid to do so since my isp might be angry...

Comment: I did the scan of the ports and host discovery. Something is clearly wrong. The host is up but i get no info about the specified ports. For some reason it says that it scanned 1000 ports and that they are all filtered... Im not too good with nmap but the ports i use schould not be in those default 1000. Thats why I use them:)


i ran nmap like this:

nmap -T4 -v -PE -PA5556 [my pub ip]

I will try to find another ip to connect from. Its wierd tho that nmap do not find my webservice etc. Also did the preset "Intense scan" using zenmap btw